# How to specify the encoding when Spark load a text file

Tags: apache-spark

I have a text file normally it is ASCII encoding, however sometimes, there is some special character which byte code is above 128, e.g. 0xD9. When I use Spark reader's text function to load this file into data frame, I find those lines with special character, the character after the special character, is missed. For example, the line's byte code sequence is 0xD9 0x20 0x40，then when I read the data frame, what I get is 0xD9 0x40.
I try to add option("encoding", "ISO-8859-1"), or option("encoding", "UTF-8") to the reader before call text function, but no effect. May I know how to let Spark text function can properly create the data frame whcih can contain all the characters？
Thanks!
PS. I use Spark2.4